# How to get value from a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link like this

```
<a id="idPage" href="#">${currentPage}</a>
```

and in this case I can get value from tag doing this way

```
$(this).text();
```

now let's the link will be like this

```
<a id="idPage" href="#">next page</a> 
<!-- the value of ${currentPage} still must to be available for a script-->
```

How to pass the value and how to get in script in this case?

Comment: `<a id="idPage" href="#" data-current-page="${currentPage}">next page</a>` and `$(this).attr('data-current-page');`

Comment: or `$(this).data('current-page')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An appropriate way to do this would be to use a `data` attribute and jQuery's `$.data` method like so.

```
<a id="idPage" href="#" data-currentpage="${currentPage}">next page</a>
```

And then to access that value,

```
$("#idPage").data('currentpage')
```

Comment: Literal copy+paste of the comment already made by another user.

Comment: Sorry this took me more than a minute to type, @AndrueAnderson haha Not that this is a terribly revolutionary or unique answer.

Comment: @AndrueAnderson - this answer used the data() instead of attr() so in my opinion not the same and it could have been written without a reload to see if there were comments

Comment: He used .data("currentPage") at the exact same time I commented to the comment on the question. What is wrong with YOU reading all sorts of conspiracies into stuff here. Do the right thing

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to store the value in a variable

**jQuery**

```
var tagValue = $("#idPage").text();
```

**JavaScript**

```
var tagValue = document.getElementById("idPage").innerHTML;
```

but it's probably the best idea to use HTML5 `data` attributes as mentioned in the comments.